# Chrome browser extensions - hooking into C functions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a Chrome extension and some parts of it need to be super high performance. I'm trying to find documentation to see if it's possible to use C extensions within the Chrome extension. Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/). You can write browser/web apps with NaCl via C or C++ (and Mono since 2.10). You can find a small tutorial [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de/chrome/nativeclient/docs/tutorial.html).